# Memory leak in svchost.exe while running a particular windows service

Tags: c#, windows, memory, service, memory-leaks

I programmed a windows service which connects to webservices on another server.
I get severe memory increase in the `svchost.exe` process. And the following warning message in the event logs.

`Warning ID: 1530
user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User....:
Process ... (\Device....\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER....\Printers\DevModePerUser`

Running environment: windows server 2008 R2 SP1 x64

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Losing 1530 handles is a drain on system resources, but is unlikely to cause a noticeable bloat in RAM usage.  If you have a "severe" memory increase it is not just because you're not releasing handles to the registry.

Comment: Where's the code for the service? There's no way of guessing what's going wrong without some code. Check if you have static objects and if you're using COM or other unmanaged resources. What's the code related to the warning you're seeing?

Comment: Event ID [1530](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947238/en-us) is logged as a Warning event. This behavior occurs because Windows automatically closes any registry handle to a user profile that is left open by an application. The application that is listed in the event detail is leaving the registry handle open.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I might have forgotten to say this memory does not happen on other machines. But happens on this one machine (Server 2008 R2 SP1 x64) Thats why i suspect its a windows issue not my program's. Any ideas?